# I can't print to VSCode's console with stdout.write

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm running a flutter application in VSCode and want to print to console using this code:

```
  stdout.write('Text');
```

But the console doesn't show anything after executing this line. Why is that?
(print statements work as expected).

EDIT:
the `print` function works fine. I just wanted to print something inside a `for` loop without a newline, that's why I was trying to use `stdout.writeln`. I ended up building the string I wanted to print in the `for` loop and printing it only once with the `print` function.

Comment: How about `stdout.writeln('Text');` ?

Comment: @SergeySolodukhin same results :( nothing gets printed.

Comment: I have this problem. print sometimes works but usually doesn't. It's massively frustrating and makes it extremely hard to trace issues

Comment: how are you running? commandline in the integrated terminal? Using the builtin debugger? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, "solved" it using `StringBuffer` and one final `print`:

```
final StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  buffer.write('$i, ');
}
print(buffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `print("Hello console");` =D

Comment: I know this is old, but just for other beginners to be aware; print() prints a new line and stdout.write() does not, so print() is not always the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem myself.

Unfortunately I can't tell you the reason why **stdout** doesn't work on terminal logs but I can tell you that you can see them using [Dart DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview) on the part of **[Logging](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/logging)**

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, please look at [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)